# Error: MSCOMCT2.OCX or one of its dependencies not

Tags: vb6, mscomct2.ocx

I am trying to run a VB application that was coded long back on Windows 2000. My current OS is windows XP SP2.

The error message is: 
"Component 'MSCOMCT2.OCX' or one of its dependencies not 
correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid"

I searched my computer for this file (this is different from MSCOMCT***L***.OCX) and didnt find it. Can someone point me how to get past this error?

Thanks,
Nag.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check out this Microsoft-based 'Help and Support' page that details where you can 'officially' download this page from.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297381

Microsoft tends to move around its content, making old pages incorrect, but as I type this, the above page lists the following location for the CAB file that contains the MSCOMCT2.OCX file that you seek;

http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/mscomct2.cab

Comment: Yeah but how do you install that cab?  Just drop in the System32 directory or what?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need the runtime files for Visual Basic ([available here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bf9a24f9-b5c5-48f4-8edd-cdf2d29a79d5&displaylang=en)).